# How does the inertia of granules within a rotating cylinder affect its inertia?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertia

If a cylinder is partially filled with granules and is rolling down an inclined plane, is there any relationship between the rotational motion of the granules and the motion of the cylinder? I'm asking because I'm doing an experiment to observe how the volume of granules in a cylinder affects its rotational inertia. I have found many resources online about the motion of granules in a rotating cylinder, but not too many on the effect on the actual cylinder. If possible, please provide references for your answers.

Comment: Hi, your question is quite correct but you should show some of your effort that what equations you found and where got stuck then I would help you.

Comment: Are you interested in finding how the granules affect rotational inertia only or do you also want how it affects the change of motion of cylinder?